# Changing the Attribute Set for a Simple Product

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, attributes, catalog

Basically the subject.

I have a simple product created with a particular attribute set.  Is there a way to change the attribute set associated with this product without having to create a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The attribute set reference is a column in the `catalog_product_entity` table. Changing that should change the attribute set.
So if you want to do it by code:

```
$product->setAttributeSetId(12)->save();
```

If you want to do it from an admin interface you can give [this extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html) a try. Even if it says it's compatible with CE 1.6.1, I used it with success on EE 1.12 (that is equivalent to CE 1.7).

Comment: Let me add, that it is no good idea to change the attributeset, if you don't know what you are doing. There are data left in the database which might make problems.

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt: You are right. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: My problem is, I'm not into it, so I don't have an examples what might be problematic :-) So it will just stay as comment ;-)

Comment: @Fabien: you should elaborate on the "if you don't know what you are doing" part. As far as I can tell from looking at the DB, attribute set ID is linked only to the EAV attribute set table. After doing what Marius has suggested, the only issues I foresee are orphaned values in the catalog EAV tables as explained here, under the "technical background":  http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html. It would personally bother me to have those extra rows abandoned in the tables, so that coule be a "problem." :)

Comment: Flagbit extension still worked for me with ce-1.9.0.1.

Comment: Flagbit extentinon just sets new attribute set ID to product and saves it. It doesn't do anything special.

Comment: Although this is an older thread, I'd figure I'd recommend n98-magerun for cleaning the orphaned values. https://github.com/peterjaap/magerun-addons

Comment: What about Magento 2 ?

Comment: @KishanPatadia For magento 2 is similar, but instead of calling `save` on the product model you should call the `save` method from the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product` class with `$product` as  parameter.