# Magento Change Product Attribute Set

Tags: product, attribute-set

I am adding products from web services for my Magento store.Problem is web services keep changing product attribute set with an interval of few days. I came to know that Attribute Set cannot be changed after a product has been created. So what is the possible way to update the product attribute set? Shall i delete the product and recreate the same product or change the attribute set from database. Which one will be better? If i delete the product will it effect on order/inventory section?

Comment: Its possible @ monojit : use the code : UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` SET `attribute_set_id` = '9' WHERE `catalog_product_entity`.`entity_id` = 15;

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change the attribute set in the default Magento installation but there are extensions that allow you to do that.
The [same question has been posted on magento.stackexchange.com](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/changing-the-attribute-set-for-a-simple-product)
There are [explanations in the answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/5132/146) on how yo do that by code, or how to do it using an extension

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I have already checked by updating attribute set from database.It works fine.For testing purpose I have updated the product which has default attribute set. But i want to update those attribute set that has one custom group containing 10 attributes.