# How can i change the Attribute Set by products?

Tags: magento2, attributes, magento-2.0, magento-2.0.5

I need to change Attribute set for some of the products but
there is no option to change them.

Comment: magento 2.0.5 ..

Comment: You can't. See: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5131/changing-the-attribute-set-for-a-simple-product?rq=1

Comment: @fschmengler well that answer was for M1, OP was asking for M2. But you still can't ^^

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara though this question is about attribute sets it is also M1 not M2 so I would leave this open.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately changing an existing product's attribute set is not possible with Magento 2 out of the box.

There's several possible options though:

- Use this extension: https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-extension-change-attribute-set
- Change the product attribute set programmatically by loading the product and then use `setAttributeSet()` method with your attribute set id
- Deal directly with the database by changing the attribute set id in the `catalog_product_entity` table. Please note that I do not recommend using that last method as I'm not 100% sure if it's totally safe to do so.

Comment: Changing directly in the database will, at worst, orphan attributes not defined in the set forever in the db. This isn't the end of the world. However, uRapidflow can do this on import and is now compatible with M2.